# Is it possible to trigger TFS aoutomated tests from the TFS test management WebUI?

Tags: testing, tfs, ui-automation

A member of my team seems to think that TFS can trigger an automated test via the WebUI test management area if an automated test is associated with a manual test?  Is that true

We are using TFS 2015 update 4.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not true. Running tests requires creating a build/release definition with appropriate test-running tasks.

TFS 2017 and 2018 can help [automate the process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=vsts) of creating an appropriate release definition for you.